# filter 'filter' - strict matching

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In a JSON array, I have 201 data objects, each with a unique ID. Using `$filter('filter'){ ... }`, I'm able to search through those results by ID. However, this is not working as I had expected, returning partial matches as well as exact matches.

For example, if I search for ID 1632, I get all results with an ID containing a 1, 6, 3, or 2, instead of the single expected result. How can I make this perform a strict match instead?

---

**EDIT:**

This is the code which returns more results than desired:

```
$filter('filter')(stories, {entry_id: id});
```

I have tried this, which returns nothing at all, even though I am passing a valid ID:

```
$filter('filter')(stories, {entry_id: id}, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

I have figured out why my 'true' flag was failing. It seems that Angular was converting my integer into a string, and due to the type mismatch it was failing. This worked:

```
$filter('filter')(stories, {entry_id: parseInt(id)}, true);
```

Hopefully this is of help to someone else.